# Expression syntax in Excel?

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm struggling with validating a regex syntax that I'd like to use in Excel (VBA). The syntax runs good in every validator engine on the net but I can't get it to work in Excel.

Could anyone help me with this and I'd most grateful.

The expression:

```
    ^.+(?<!/)(?=/?[RP]\d)
```

Data to validate: ABC12345/67/R1A

Expected result: ABC12345/67

Comment: Try this `^.+(?=/[RP]\d)`

Comment: Sorry, but did not work...

Comment: Check out [this](http://regexr.com?371tb)

Comment: Thank you for the effort but my expression syntax is ok when I run it in a test program BUT I can't get it to work in Excel and VBA, that is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this regex `^.+(?<!/)(?=/?[RP]\d)` as its not giving the expected output.
It works with `^.+(?=/[RP]\d)`. Below is sample code.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim stringToValidate As String
    Dim stringResult As String


    stringToValidate = "ABC12345/67/R1A"
    stringResult = getData(stringToValidate)


End Sub

Function getData(ByVal str As String) As String
    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegEx.Global = True

    objRegEx.Pattern = "^.+(?=/[RP]\d)"

    Set allMatches = objRegEx.Execute(str)

    For i = 0 To allMatches.Count - 1
        result = result & allMatches.Item(i)
    Next

    getData = result
End Function
```